# javafx graphics without a window

Tags: java, javafx

This might be a wierd question but is it possible to draw some sort of graphics without a window using javafx?

To clarify I want to write a circle at the bottom left corner of the screen where everything but the circle is the underlying window. So just removing the titlebar is not really enough

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're asking. What do you mean "everything but the circle is the underlying window"? Did you forget a word here? "everything but the circle is IN the underlying window"? Why wouldn't the circle be in that window too, just on top of everything else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for a transparent stage - this puts a red circle on the bottom left of the primary monitor. This might help you in the direction you want to go.

```
public class TransparentStage extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        stage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);
        Circle c = new Circle(30);
        c.setFill(Color.RED);
        VBox box = new VBox();
        box.getChildren().add(c);
        final Scene scene = new Scene(box,300, 250);
        scene.setFill(null);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setX(20);
        stage.setY(Screen.getPrimary().getBounds().getHeight() - 100);
        stage.show();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Some sort of transparent window like below

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.StageStyle;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        stage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);
        Text text = new Text("!");
        text.setFont(new Font(40));
        VBox box = new VBox();
        box.getChildren().add(text);
        final Scene scene = new Scene(box,300, 250);
        scene.setFill(null);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

source : http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/JavaFX/TRANSPARENTwindow.htm